# Set member function pointer to free function pointer

Tags: c++, pointers, function-pointers, pointer-to-member

I am working on a simple engine coded in c++ and wrapped with ctypes. I'm working on window class and I want to give the engine user ability to set draw and update functions. I have the following code:

window.h

```cpp
#pragma once
#include <GL/glew.h>
#include <GLFW/glfw3.h>
class window
{
public:
    GLFWwindow* wnd;

    window(int width, int height, const char* title);
    void close();

    void update();
    void (window::*draw)();

    void setDrawFunction(void (window::*)());
    void setUpdateFunction(int*);
};
```

window.cpp

```
#include <GL/glew.h>
#include <GLFW/glfw3.h>

#include "window.h"

void default_draw() {
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
}

void default_update() {
    
}

window::window(int width, int height, const char* title)
{
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_SAMPLES, 4);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MAJOR, 3);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MINOR, 3);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_COMPAT_PROFILE, GL_TRUE);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_PROFILE, GLFW_OPENGL_CORE_PROFILE);

    wnd = glfwCreateWindow(width, height, title, NULL, NULL);

    if (wnd == NULL) { glfwTerminate(); return; }

    glfwMakeContextCurrent(wnd);

    if (glewInit() != GLEW_OK) {
        glfwTerminate();
        return;
    }

    setDrawFunction((void)(window::*)()default_draw);
}

void window::close() {
    glfwDestroyWindow(this->wnd);
}

void window::update() {
    default_update();
}

void window::setDrawFunction(void (window::*fnptr)()) {
    draw = fnptr;
}
```

This doesn't work. Am I missing something obvious or it's just impossible to accomplish this way. If so, is there any way I could achieve this? All I need is to be able to overdrive function, so I can do this in python, using ctypes.

Errors i get:
109 expression before calling must have a function (pointer) type
29 expression expected
18 expected ")"

Comment: `default_draw` is not a member function. The fact that you have to add the explicit C cast `(void)(window::*)()` to make the call to `setDrawFunction` compile is a good indication that you aren't using it correctly. You need to give it a `window` member function.

Comment: The problem is, I still need to somehow override the draw function outside of class.

Comment: You might be interested to learn about [`std::function`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function).

Comment: Sorry, the header is not actual. It is now corrected and the problem is the same. I will post corrected version of it and errors I get in a moment

Comment: Consider using `void(member*)` functions instead of `void()` if you still want an object oriented solution while being C (and ctypes) compatible. The draw function can then call the draw function with `draw(this);`.

Comment: The way `window` is defined now, it is not possible to define new behaviors without changing `window`. So it is not extensible at all. You should not expect to be able to "override" the draw behavior expect for those that are already provided by the `class`.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux Thanks, I will try to use void(member*) functions. This should be actually give me possibility to use this function in the same way in python and C++

Answer (score 1):

Use of a member function pointer of `window` as a member variable is not appropriate.

I can think of the following options to address the issue.

### Option 1

Make `draw` a non-member function pointer.

```
void (*draw)();

void setDrawFunction(void (*func)());
```

### Option 2

Make `draw` a `std::function`

```
std::function<void()> draw;

void setDrawFunction(std::function<void()> func);
```

### Option 3

Use a separater class/interface for drawing.

```
std::unique_ptr<DrawingAgent> draw;

void setDrawingAgent(std::unique_ptr<DrawingAgent> agent);
```

where

```
class DrawingAgent
{
   public:
      virtual void draw(window*); // Draw in given window.
};
```

---

Of the above options, I would recommend using **Option 3**. It cleanly separates the *window* aspect of your application from the *drawing* functionality.

Comment: Actually I used option 1 recommended to me by @FrancoisAndrieux, but thanks for response